# Key notes and advice on building a login mechanism in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration

I've built a login/registration mechanism for my current web app but i'm not really happy about it.

Can anyone give me some good advice on some thumb rules to keep in mind while rebuilding it (code & db structure)?

I intend to also include a login option through Facebook, Twitter and OpenID.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) all user input properly
2. [Encrypt](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) any personal information
3. If storing passwords always use a [salt](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
4. If using a 3rd party login use SSL on your own site and don't assume incoming data is safe

Comment: Actually the #1 is useless if you are building a PDO-based app. And using PDO is highly recommended.

Comment: unless your app is distributed, in which case it will then only work on later versions of PHP